# Populate combobox with unique values without scripting.dictionnary

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

So far I found a way to populate my combobox but it does not work (Error 429) when it tries to create the object.
here is the code I found :

```
Dim v, e
c = 2
ld = 8
lf = 128
With Sheets("2017-Sem1").Range(Cells(ld, c), Cells(lf, c))
    v = .Value
End With
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionnary")
    .comparemode = 1
    For Each e In v
        If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
    Next
    If .Count Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
End Sub
```

First of all, I do not undersand exactly what the code is doing, I'll be grateful if you could enlight me. 
Second it seems that "scripting.dictionnary" does not exist on my computer:
I tried

```
dim dict as scripting.Dictionnary
```

and it returns a compilation error at once.

So, to my understanding so far, I will not be able to use it (absent DLL, and I cannot go into the folders at my work).
Does anyone have an alternative solution that I can use ?

Thank you, 
PEagle

Comment: You need to add the reference to the dictionary. It's called "Microsoft Scripting Library". You can find the references in the VBA editor `Tools>References`

Comment: The reference is not in... according to what I found here : 
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=66682
I would have to download and install something which is prohibited in my workplace...
Anything I'm not seeing ?

Comment: You have 2 methods in your post, in your code you are using **Late Binding** by using `With CreateObject("scripting.dictionnary")`. However, later in your post you are asking about **Early Binding** by `dim dict as scripting.Dictionnary` , so which method do you want to use ?  And it should be `With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")` - You have one **n** too many

Comment: Dim dict as scripting.Dictionary was just to see if the library was accessible, which it was (and still is) not.
To use it in any of the method, I should have access to "Microsoft Scripting Library" but it is not listed in tools/reference.
Installing it is still impossible to me because of IT policy at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this slightly differently - you don't necessarily need a `Dictionary` (or `Collection`). Just use the `Combobox.List` object. This `VBA` code takes values in range `A1:A10` and only adds to your combobox if it's unique. The code is designed to go in your **`UserForm Module`**

```
Sub Userform_Initialize()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")

    For Each r In rng
        AddUnique r.value
    Next r
End Sub

Sub AddUnique(value As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim inList As Boolean

    inList = False
    With Me.ComboBox1
        For i = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ComboBox1.List(i) = value Then
                inList = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If Not inList Then
            .AddItem value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I tested the code and it works nicely for me. Let me know if you have any troubles

Comment: Works fine except for two things specific to my file (that I did not mention here):
 - Does not work with numbers (keeps adding them to the list)
- I work with merged cells (2 rows each time) and it adds the "empty" value once
And a last question in addition, how can I make my list sorted in alphabetical order? 
Thank you for your time and close to perfect answer.